# Accessing values from role defaults

Tags: ansible

I need to access the values from role defaults in the context of other hosts in the inventory. While the values defined in the inventory are available, the role defaults are not.

The following example demonstrates my problem:

```
#inventory.yml:
all:
    hosts:
        srv01:
            ansible_connection: local
            user_name: srv-1-user
            domain: example.com
        srv02:
            ansible_connection: local
            user_name: srv-2-user
            domain: example.net

#role-a/defaults.yml
user_email_address: {{ user_name }}@{{ domain }}

#role-a/main.yml
- set_fact:
    _values: "{{ _values | default([]) + [hostvars[item]['user_email_address'] | default(user_email_address)] }}"
  with_inventory_hostnames:
    - all
- name: output
  debug: var=_values

#site.yml
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook

- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: role-a
    tags: 'role-a'

#command:
ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml site.yml
```

The code above generates (as expected) the following output:

```
ok: [srv02] => {
    "_values": [
        "srv-2-user@example.net", 
        "srv-2-user@example.net"
    ]
}
ok: [srv01] => {
    "_values": [
        "srv-1-user@example.com", 
        "srv-1-user@example.com"
    ]
}
```

What I need is the following output:

```
ok: [srv02] => {
    "_values": [
        "srv-1-user@example.net", 
        "srv-2-user@example.net"
    ]
}
ok: [srv01] => {
    "_values": [
        "srv-1-user@example.com", 
        "srv-2-user@example.com"
    ]
}
```

It is not viable defining all values in the inventory. This problem makes role defaults in this context unusable for me.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could define `user_email_address` as

```
user_email_address: "{{ hostvars[item]['user_name'] }}@{{ hostvars[item]['domain'] }}"
```

to take advantage of the lazy loading.